# How to bind post variables

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mysqli, bind

just a quick question about binding in php

I know if you do something like

```
$select = update my_table set name ='".$posted_name.'" where id=1;
```

and that is subjected to sql injection

but how will you bind the query below

```
$select = update my_table set name ='".$posted_name[$a].'" where id=1;
```

IN my bind array this is how I am binding anything `without` `[$a]`

for any example with the first statement I am doing

```
   $select = update my_table set name =:p_update_name where id=1;

   $bind_update = array('p_update_name' => $t_update_name);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @SureshKamrushi so in PDO you will do `$stmt->bindParam(1, $name[$a]);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: thanks @YourCommonSense but it doesn't show the a method with `$posted_name[$a]`. it just includes a standard statement.

Comment: method with $posted_name[$a] has **absolutely nothing to do with prepared statements**

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: can you try and cover both pdo and mysqli method in your answer please. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to make all the names equal.

```
$select = "update my_table set name =:whatever where id=1";
$bind_update = array('whatever' => $random_variable);
```

will do. so it can be **any** variable you can think of. As long as it's scalar variable though

Comment: what about the `[$a]` wouldnt i need to include that in the statement or the binding?

Comment: ok I see your answer, so basically the way you are binding `$select = update my_table set name ='".$posted_name[$a].'" where id=1;` is the same as `$select = update my_table set name ='".$posted_name.'" where id=1;`

Comment: There is no binding in your example

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I updated my question to show how I am binding, i am using array binding(oracle) but its query is no different and the function that was written is in php.

Comment: All I can do is only repeat what I said before: there is absolutely no reason for the variables have the same name with placeholders.